# How to use multiple versions Jersey (1.8.x and 2.15) in one Java project?

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have two **maven** projects: projA and projB

**projB** depends on **projA**

**projB** depends on Jersey 2.15

**projA** depends on hbase-testing-utils

hbase-testing-utils depends Jersey 1.8.x

If **projB** declares dependency on **projA** without any exclusions, then **projB**'s tests fail because they use the wrong version (1.8.x) of some class in Jersey project.

If **projB** declares dependency on **projA** with exclusions for jersey components, then the above problem goes away. But the new problem is that during test run, **projA** is not able to find ServletContainer (Jersey 1.8.x) because of the exclusion. **projA** uses hbase testing utils to spin up an in-memory hbase server which underneath uses Jersey 1.8.x.

I need to use Jersey 2.15 in projB but I also need to exclude Jersey 1.8.x from projA to avoid Null Pointer Exceptions as a result of wrong version classes being used.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Jersey 2 is implementation of JAX-RS 2. Jersey 1.8 is implementation of JAX-RS 1. JAX-RS 2 is not backward compatible and some of the method signatures conflict with each other. You can not include Jersy1.8 and Jersey2 in the same project. It will compile but will fail during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can exclude jersey from the dependency on projA, and add it separately but with scope "test".

this should make it available for the test, but not during the other phaces.

Comment: I need dependency on both versions of jersey in "test" scope at the same time.